# Solving an equation from a contest

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I was studying for a math contest and I came across this problem. I am not sure how to solve it as I have never encountered a problem like this before. Does anyone have any hints or helpful tips? That would be really helpful.

If $m$ and $n$ are positive integers that satisfy the equation $3m^3 = 5n^5$, the smallest
possible value for $m + n$ is

Comment: Hint:  consider the prime factorizations of $m,n$.

Comment: Same method(s) as in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1):

OP asks for hints only, so I will not present a full solution.

It should be apparent that $3\mid n$ and $5\mid m$. So the problem is to find how many factors of $3$ and $5$ are contained in each of $m,n$

If $m$ has factors of $3$ in it, then the number of factors of $3$ on the left will be $3r+1$ and the number of factors of $3$ in the left will be $5s$. We want to find the smallest $r,s$ such that the number of factors of $3$ on each side of the equation is the same, i.e. $3r+1=5s$. The smallest solution is $r=3,s=2$

If $n$ has factors of $5$ in it, then the number of factors of $5$ on the right will be $5u+1$ and the number of factors of $5$ in the left will be $3v$. We want to find the smallest $u,v$ such that the number of factors of $5$ on each side of the equation is the same, i.e. $5u+1=3v$. I leave this at the hint stage for OP to solve.

If the smallest solutions are found and substituted into the original equation, the resulting equation will look like $3^a5^b=3^a5^b$ for some $a,b$ which OP should be able to find, from which $m,n$ can be readily obtained.

If OP needs further hints, ask in the comments and I will fill in a little further.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @Jaireet Sahal: HINT: Assuming real $m,n$ ignoring integer solution. Euler -Lagrange optimization with object/constraint gives you $ m/n=5/3 .$ The integer solution can be seen here directly.

Answer (score -1):

We have $3$ on LHS , hence RHS must have $3$ , which gives us $3|n$.
We have $5$ on RHS , hence LHS must have $5$ , which gives us $5|m$.

Similar thinking gives us $15|n$ & $15|m$.

We want minimum, we want no other factors.
Hence let $n=3^{A} \cdot 5^{B}$ & $m=3^{C} \cdot 5^{D}$ and make the Equation.

$3 \cdot 3^{3A} \cdot 5^{3B}=5 \cdot 3^{5C} \cdot 5^{5D}$
$3^{3A+1} \cdot 5^{3B}=3^{5C} \cdot 5^{5D+1}$

Equate the Powers :
$3A+1=5C$
$3B=5D+1$

We want minimum values of $A,B,C,D$ hence we get :
$C=2$ & $A=3$
$B=2$ & $D=1$

Hence $n=3^{3} \cdot 5^{2}$ & $m=3^{2} \cdot 5^{1}$

We get $n=675$ & $45$ & $m+n=720$ minimum. Higher values of $A,B,C,D$ will give values of $m+n$.

[[ thanks to user Keith Backman who made me recheck & thanks to user Dan who confirm my updated Answer ]]

Comment: Your logic is faulty, and there is a solution.

Comment: Indeed: $m = 675, n = 45$ is one such solution.

Comment: I have corrected the logic , thanks @KeithBackman

Comment: I have arrived at that same solution now , thanks @Dan